# IFS does not work "temporarily"

Tags: bash

I'm trying to output `a,b,c`,

This does not work:

```
a=(a b c)
IFS=, echo "${a[*]}"
```

But this works:

```
a=(a b c)
IFS=,
echo "${a[*]}"
```

Anyone know why the first one does not work?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the variable is expanded *before* the new value of IFS is actually set. This is described at https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Simple-Command-Expansion

Use a subshell to set the value without affecting the current shell:

```bash
(IFS=,; echo "${a[*]}")
```